# Creating a condition to make certain Columns visible

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to make this work! I keep getting an object defined error.

```
Sub Visible_Month_shop_analysis()

Dim c As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each c In ws.Range("c1:jb1")
            c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            If c.Value > 0 Then
                c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False                
            End If
        Next c

    Next ws


End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what's wrong here, but the inside of your two for loops could be rewritten to just one line: `c.EntireColumn.Hidden = (c.Value > 0)`. As for the problem itself, which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Also, potentially unrelated to the error: `c.value > 0` will return true if the cell has been set to `""`. Are these formulas in row 1? Are the cells truly empty or do they have some value, even `""`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Public Sub Visible_Month_shop_analysis()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Range("C1:JB1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        For Each c In ws.Range("C1:JB1")
            If c.Value > 0 Then '<<  Could test If Not IsEmpty(c) ...if testing for non-empty
                c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next c
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And yes, as mentioned in other answer, ensure sheets are unlocked or at least that format column box is unchecked for sheet protection options.

Comment: Any feedback on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you were not the original creator of the worksheet, it is possible that a column(s) in the worksheet is locked. Remove the protection of the columns and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` instead of `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` (or use the name of the workbook).  Maybe the right workbook is not activated when the code is running.